# How to allow null for float in EF?

Tags: entity-framework

How to allow float types Nullable in the database using entity framework?
The following line does not work.

```
public float? MyAge{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved. i wasn't running migration package after doing changes to model.